# Prolog error when adding to heaps

Tags: prolog, heap

I am getting an error when adding elements to a heap in prolog.
When I add a priority, key pair to the heap it adds it as `t(Priority,Key,[])` which causes my program to crash further down the line.

Here's the code in question:

```
astar(Start,Seed,Target,Found) :-
    empty_heap(Heap),
    h(Start,Priority,Target),
    add_to_heap(Heap,Priority,Start,Newheap),
    search(Newheap,Seed,Target).
```

Note: I am using `gtrace`, and the returned values from `empty_heap` and `h` are bother correct (`heap(nil,0)` and `1`).

All help appreciated!

Comment: What exactly means that your program crashes?

Comment: no matter what is inside the heap, why u no use get_from_heap or min_of_heap